# Intel and AMD graphics not detecting drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

### Disclamer

Hi all,

This is my first time posting here so I apologies if I get the format wrong or give to little/much information.

### The Short Version

Long and short of it is that, my graphics drivers (AMD/Intel) on my laptop are not install/recognised.

### The Long Version

I am currently using a Dell XPS 15 9575 1-2, which uses two graphics chips (AMD Radeon RX Vega M GL / 870, and HD Graphics 630). Bellow is a photo of the about on my ubuntu installation.

[Ubuntu About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO9MC.jpg)

While I am able to boot it into recovery mode when I try and boot ubuntu normally the screen freaks out and just start turning pixels on and off at random.

In recovery mode I ran "sudo lshw -c video" [full results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EvS0.jpg) and as you can clearly see there is no driver listed.

After doing some research I found that both of there graphics chips should have drivers already installed in the Kernal however they have either not been installed on my distro or there are not being detected.

Please could someone advise?

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Any current release should support both graphics with included open-source drivers.

Comment: while I know you are right, it would appear that those drivers they are not being detected as shown in the lshw command that I ran. is there a way to tell Ubuntu to use those drivers manually?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.